# Delete Applications - Self Made With Gtk Tutorial

Tags: vala

I've been playing around with Gtk and vala and I love it; however, I've created two simple apps that I don't know how to delete from my system.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still have the source code, use `sudo ninja uninstall` inside the build folder.

If you removed the build folder by any chance, run `meson build --prefix=/usr` to recreate the build folder, followed by `cd build && ninja`.

If you no longer have the source code, you'll have to manually remove your binary from `/usr/bin/` and the .desktop file from `/usr/share/applications/`. Also, look inside `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` and `/usr/share/metainfo/` for any xml files.